# Postrgres Restore/Replication

Tags: postgresql, restore, database-replication

I have a database which is the one the application is using (production), and another one to solve problems(develop).

They both the same databases but one the one to solve problems we use to resolve incidents and to develop new projects.

Every night I take the dump from the production database and restore on the other one. But as the database grows, this process started to take too long. So we decided to do a dump excluding some of the tables that we won't use on the "resolving problem"/developing scenario.

But now this situation achieved the limit situation, it's taking too long and there's no more tables we can exclude.

Ps: We need the database to be restored everyday because we need the information from yesterday's data to solve the problems.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually doing a full dump and restore every night, a better solution would be to set up master / slave streaming replication.

In this scenario your production database would be your 'master' and your develop database your 'slave'.  Updates made to the master will be automatically synced to your slave database.

For PostgreSQL you may want to take a look at [Slony-I](http://www.slony.info/) which provides this functionality.  The documentation is quite helpful.

Comment: But what happens with the modifications that we do along the day on the develop database? Will it recognize the modification and applies master's database structure? And i don't want to update the database as the master is modified. I want that at one time of the day, slave synchronize structure and data with the master.

Comment: But if you are restoring your develop database from production every night then you are currently losing any modifications to develop are you not?  Also, how large is your database and how long is it taking to restore?

Comment: Yes, but I don't mind to lose the modifications, I am only asking if this is going to happen because that's actually what I want to happen. It is taking about 7 hours to restore.

Comment: Yes, you would lose modifications to your slave.  I suggested streaming replication because it would spread out the data transfer throughout the course of the day.  However, if you need this to happen at the end of the day, then you may have to look at other solutions.  Is date-range partitioning on your tables an option?

Comment: No, it's not an option. I have to restore the information only once a day and not as the production information changes. so that wouldn't be an option as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SymmetricDS Professional](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) or [SymmetricDS Open Source](http://www.symmetricds.org/).  It fully supports PostgreSQL replication.   By default it would push/pull changes every minute but you could schedule those jobs to run only every 24 hours (if I understood your requirement correctly).  The benefit to this would be it would only push the changes that occurred for a given day rather than the entire data set thus reducing the time of the "restore" a great deal.  You also have the ability to pick which tables your interested in synching or not synching.

Comment: But what about if I do a change on the development base? Let's say I created a table on the development base and the table doesn't exists on the production base. Is this table going to be deleted with this process or not?

Comment: No it does not sync schema changes automatically (so a table would not be dropped through the tool in this case).   In addition there is a parameter to ignore missing tables so that batches for this table will not be marked in error if the table from the source is not found on the target.

Comment: Also if you are just adding columns to the development base this will not cause any issues they will just come back as null from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use pg_restore with -j option (parallel restore)? It usually speed up a lot by using all available cpu cores instead of one. Dump should be created in custom format (-F c option for pg_dump) otherwise parallel restore won't work.

Or perhaps better approach to use pg_basebackup which is only limited by network speed and disk read/write speed.